# Page_PreRender fires twice on first load in session

Tags: asp.net, session

When I run the web application, I notice that Page_PreRender is fired twice. **This only happens the first time in a new session.** It does not happen if I refresh the page, or on postbacks.
I use .NET framework 3.5 and the built in ajax functionality.

- <sup>The problem is *not*
  related to `img` tag with empty `src`
  attribute (which I have seen other posts with similar problem
  has mentioned). I know this because I see this in
  both FireFox and IE. The posts I saw
  about this stated that this was not a
  problem in IE. I have also searched
  and found no img tags with empty src
  in the generated page source, so it
  should not be this.</sup>
- <sup>I have also made a simple test
  page where I have included some of
  the functionality, and this does not
  happen.</sup>

Have anyone any suggestions on what happens?

**Note:**
It is the entire page cycle that is firing twice, not just render.

Comment: Do you have any AJAX calls on your page that are run when the page first loads? If you place a test in your Page_PreRender event for 
if (IsCallback){}
does it return true?

Comment: I have javascript eventhandler for pageLoaded and initializeRequest, registered through the api in `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()`, but I have also done this in my test page where the problem is not happening. I tried to check for `IsCallback`, but this is false in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced it; it's probably not what you are experiencing, but I'll enter it here anyway; I've noticed it when the application does a Response.Redirect at the PreRender level, which a redirect does not stop current execution, but makes it appear the event happens twice...

Again, probably not related, but including it just in case.

Comment: You are right - it's not related to my problem. I have no redirect in the code in question.

Answer (score -1):

I copied some code that states:

```
Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_PreRender)
```

I did not realize that this code fire for second time my `Page_PreRender` event. 
When I comment it, never fire twice.